# Override/reimplement enum in derived class

Tags: c++, oop, enums

I'm developing a database program for my college project.
I have base class which represents `Invoice` and derived class for representing a `CorrectedInvoice`. Finally I want to store the data to the file, so I use enums to indicate in what order are they stored:

```
enum FIELD_ORDER
{
    ID, 
    IVOICE_NUM, 
    TIME, 
    CLIENT_ID,
    COST,

    SIZE // fields' length
};
```

In derived class we have additional field indicating which Invoice do we correct, also the fields' order changes.
I tried to surround the enums with `#ifdef` blocks, but the preprocessor always runs first through base class file, so I'm unable to declare desired enum for each class. How can I achieve such effect? Is there a better way to store the order? I use it in (de)serialization and I would like for it to be flexible and usable in loop/switch statements.

@edit
I forgot to mention that fields order doesn't change at runtime, so that's why I came up with enums.

Comment: A typo, field names are just for example.

Comment: You should learn to take more care, if you want to be a good programmer. The error was really obvious.

Comment: You can have a `protected` or `private` `virtual` function, say `getFieldOrder`, which returns an `std::vector` or `std::array` (if the number of fields is constant) containing `FIELD_ORDER` objects in the order that's proper for the given class.

Comment: I translated them from my native language while writing this post, I didn't even invented them, they were predefined by the teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a suggestion, declare the enum inside the class like as follows,

```
class BaseClass
{
 public:
    enum FIELD_ORDER
    {
      ID, 
      IVOICE_NUM, 
      TIME, 
      CLIENT_ID,
      COST,

      SIZE // fields' length
   };
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
 public:
    enum FIELD_ORDER
    {
       //Derived Version
    };
};
```

Then use the following way to access the corresponding version of FIELD_ORDER

```
BaseClass::FIELD_ORDER
```

Answer (score 2):

First I would mention to research serializing techniques, that is the term used for transforming a class in memory into a permanent form.

It sounds like you are using the ordering of the various enums to mean something. That is not how enums should be used, think of the actual underlying values as an implementation detail (unless you are writing them to disk).

I would avoid using an enum here in general because there isn't any enumeration that you want. In theory you could define a virtual method to determine the order, but that wouldn't allow adding additional fields.

Instead what you should do is create a virtual method to handle serializing the class to somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the code below may help you.

```
#define INVOICE_ENUM true
#define CORRECTED_INVOICE_ENUM false
template<bool>
class FIELD_ORDER
{
public:
    enum {
    ID, 
    IVOICE_NUM, 
    TIME, 
    CLIENT_ID,
    COST,

    SIZE // fields' length
    };
};

template<>
class FIELD_ORDER<false>
{
public:
enum {
    ID, 
    TIME, 
    CLIENT_ID,
    COST,
    IVOICE_NUM,
    SIZE // fields' length
};
};

cout<<FIELD_ORDER<INVOICE_ENUM>::TIME;
cout<<FIELD_ORDER<CORRECTED_INVOICE_ENUM>::TIME;
```